# WCF websocket doesn't close on disconnect

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying using self-hosted websockets in C#. Basically my current test is working, but I when the websocket is closed by client, the code is still trying to send data. 
Do I miss something? Is there a better (built-in) approach of how to work with websockets?

(I'm using .Net Framework 4.8)

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebSocketTest
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestWebSocketCallback
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
        Task SendResult(Message msg);
    }

    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ITestWebSocketCallback))]
    public interface ITestWebSocket
    {

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, Action = "*")]
        Task StartSending(Message msg);
    }

    public class TestWebSocket : ITestWebSocket
    {
        public async Task StartSending(Message msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started sending");
            var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ITestWebSocketCallback>();
            try
            {
                var random = new Random();
                var result = 100.00;

                while (((IChannel)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                {
                    await callback.SendResult(CreateMessage($"{result}"));
                    result += random.NextDouble();
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Channel closed");
            }
            catch (WebSocketException wse)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"WebSocketException: {wse.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {e.Message}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Finished sending");
        }

        Message CreateMessage(string msgText)
        {
            var msg = ByteStreamMessage.CreateMessage(new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msgText)));
            msg.Properties["WebSocketMessageProperty"] = new WebSocketMessageProperty
            {
                MessageType = WebSocketMessageType.Text
            };
            return msg;
        }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/TestWS");
            // Create the ServiceHost.
            var _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestWebSocket), baseAddress);

            //// Enable metadata publishing.
            var behaviour = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            behaviour.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            behaviour.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            _host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behaviour);

            // Create WebSocket
            var binding = new CustomBinding();
            binding.Elements.Add(new ByteStreamMessageEncodingBindingElement());
            var transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
            transport.WebSocketSettings.TransportUsage = WebSocketTransportUsage.Always;
            transport.WebSocketSettings.CreateNotificationOnConnection = true;
            binding.Elements.Add(transport);
            _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestWebSocket), binding, "");

            // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages.
            Console.WriteLine("Opening websocket...");
            try
            {
                _host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Opened!");
                Console.WriteLine(baseAddress);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Cannot open: {e.Message}");
                throw;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I except the output is someting like:

```
Started sending
Channel closed
Finished sending
```

but I get:

```
Started sending
WebSocketException
Finished sending
```

Comment: In my opinion the client can't know that the connection is closed before "missing" a send. When i was working with web socket i just considered the connection closed after an error when sending a packet.

Comment: What is exactly the WebSocketException you are getting?

Comment: @Guilhem:The client itself is disconnecting. But the server still tries to send.

Comment: @Maxim: The inner exception is: "An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection."

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is impossible.  As mentioned in the official document (duplex communication equal to websocket since WCF achieve duplex communication by using websocket protocol).

> The duplex model doesn't automatically detect when a service or client
>   closes its channel. So if a client unexpectedly terminates, by default
>   the service will not be notified, or if a service unexpectedly
>   terminates, the client will not be notified. If you use a service that
>   is disconnected, the CommunicationException exception is raised.
>   Clients and services can implement their own protocol to notify each
>   other if they so choose. For more information on error handling, see
>   WCF Error Handling

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/duplex-services
In my opinion, we could send a heartbeat package to prove that the client is live, or we could define and implement another service contract, or use below OperationContext,etc.

```
OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += delegate
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
};
```